# k8s resources overview planning

Tags: kubernetes, resources, monitoring

We are planning on delivering small k8s clusters to clients with our application on top.
Currently we are struggling on see what resources we actually need. At average we are running 20-30 pods in the system.
While getting resources requests and limits per deployment is not hard to see.
It is hared to get full view of all requests or all limits resources for all pods that are running in the cluster. At least in an automated way.

Is there prebuild dashboard in Grafana or some kind of kubectl command that would collect all of the requests and limits for all pods running in the k8s cluster?
The result should be a "nice" report for all resource requirements.

Since we are delivering a "static" cluster to clients there is no hpa roles in our clusters.

So far we have done manual check per each pod and write it in Excel table which is not time efficient and repeatable.

Answer (score 0):

Hi `skolko` you can use prometheus for monitoring your kubernetes cluster there are various options available like monitoring individual deployments, monitoring entire cluster and monitoring each pod individually. Follow this [document](https://devopscube.com/setup-prometheus-monitoring-on-kubernetes/) for setting up the prometheus monitoring for kubernetes and this [document](https://gist.github.com/max-rocket-internet/6a05ee757b6587668a1de8a5c177728b) for getting an overview on metrics available for monitoring.

Comment: Hi `skolko` is your issue resolved..? comment here if you need additional support, upvote or accept this if this helped you in solving your query.